# why click event of am-charts fired twice in touch device?

Tags: javascript, android, amcharts

I am using am-map in my android app.the click event fired twice in touch device,how prevent the second time?and how recognize click event happens in the mapObjectes rejoin or in the div tag ?

**edit :**

this is my html code.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ammap.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ammap/maps/js/worldLowAfrica.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ammap/lang/fa.js"></script>
    <script src="ammap/themes/patterns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/hobyMain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body id="myMap">
    <!--<div id="myMap"> </div>-->
</body>
```

Comment: could you post index.html.